# Record command call and output terminal

Tags: linux, logging, monitoring, audit-logging

For analytic purpose I need to configure linux system to record all execution of specific process whenever they was run. I was trying auditd/auditbeat and works great, propely logs all commands with paramateres set by user, but I can't catch terminal output. How I can redirect stdout/stderr of this specific command execution, without changing method of call this command (like adding redirect of file descriptor `1>filename` etc. )

Comment: Have you considered replacing the program with a wrapper script?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [what's on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Possibly, your question may be better suited for the [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com)? (Note that Stack Overflow has [many sister sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites)). In any case, be sure to check their respective help pages (what's on-topic) before posting your question.

Comment: @thatotherguy Thanks. Yes I did, but also looking for "more general" resolution of this task.